# iOS New-Contact-Style Segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uipresentingcontroller

I am trying to emulate the iOS contacts segueing between two view controllers.

I have a simple `Person` class given by:

```
class Person {
    var name = ""
}
```

and a `UIViewController` that contains an array of `Person`, which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`:

```
class PeopleViewController: UIViewController {

    var people = [Person]()
    var selectedPerson: Person?

    switch segueIdentifier(for: segue) {
    case .showPerson:
        guard let vc = segue.destination as? PersonViewController else { fatalError("!") }
        vc.person = selectedPerson 
    }

}
```

This controller uses a **Show** segue to `PersonViewController` to display the `selectedPerson`:

```
class PersonViewController: UIViewController {
    var person: Person!
}
```

`PeopleViewController` can also add a new `Person` to the array of `Person`. The `NewPersonViewController` is presented **modally**, however:

```
class NewPersonViewController: UIViewController {
    var person: Person?
}
```

If a new `Person` is added, I want `NewPersonViewController` to dismiss but **show** the new `Person` in the `PersonViewController` that is part of the navigation stack. My best guess for doing this is:

```
extension NewPersonViewController {
    func addNewPerson() {
        weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController
        if let cvc = pvc?.childViewControllers.first as? PeopleViewController {
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                cvc.selectedPerson = self.person
                cvc.performSegue(withIdentifier: .showPerson, sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, **(1)** I'm not too happy about forcing the downcast to `UINavigationController` as I would have expected `self.presentingViewController` to be of type `PeopleViewController`? And **(2)**, is there a memory leak in the closure as I've used `weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController` for `pvc` but not for `cvc`? Or, finally **(3)** is there a better way of doing this?

Many thanks for any help, suggestions etc.

Comment: If you're building a contact list type thing, wouldn't it be best to use a tableview controller? The way I would do is just like the Contact list. Use plus sign button and popup up the Add Contact view controller, then if you want to save it, add a done button commit to the database (i.e. the list of people). Dismiss the Add Contact vc and when you go back to the table view, reload the data.

Comment: @u84six Hi thanks for your suggestion. I am using a table view to represent the `people` array. When you click a `Person` in the table view it becomes the selected Person and segues to the `PersonViewController`. I want to segue from the `NewPersonViewController` directly to the `PersonViewController` when the "done" button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) I'm not too happy about forcing the downcast to UINavigationController as I would have expected self.presentingViewController to be of type PeopleViewController?

There is nothing wrong in downcasting. I would definitely remove force unwrapping.

> (2), is there a memory leak in the closure as I've used weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController for pvc but not for cvc?

I think, there is none.

> (3) is there a better way of doing this?

You can present newly added contact from NewContactVC. When you about to dismiss, call dismiss on presentingVC.

```
// NewPersonViewController.swift
func addNewPerson() {
// New person is added
// Show PeopleViewController modally
}
```

Note: Using presentingViewController this way will dismiss top two/one **Modal(s)**. You will see only top view controller getting dismissed.
If you can't determine how many modals going to be, you should look-into different solution or possibly redesigning navigation flow.

```
// PeopleViewController.swift
func dismiss() {
    if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController {
       presentingVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know **why** the `presentingViewController` is a `UINavigationController` rather than a `PeopleViewController`, please?

Comment: @Alex when you present view, it is presented from root view controller. If you are using tabs, it will be tabviewcontrollers as it is rootviewcontroller